# Retrieve all elements on laravel collection

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent, orm, laravel-7

I've just started using Laravel. I'm currently creating some sort of "Instagram" app as an example. So I have 4 tables. Users, Images, Comments and Likes. I've already created the "Models" using the php artisan command make:model and included some data to the database. The thing is, after creating the relationships of the models like.

```
use App\Image;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments';
    protected $primaryKey = 'CommentId';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'UserId');
    }

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Image', 'ImageId');
    }
}
```

And doing the same thing on the Image Model

```
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'images';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ImageId';

    public function comments() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'CommentId');
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like', 'LikeId');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'UserId');
    }
```

I can't get all the comments on an image, after executing:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $images = Image::all();


    foreach ($images as $image) {
        echo "Uploaded By: ".$image->user->FirstName."<br>";
        echo "<strong>Comments</strong><br>";

        foreach ($image->comments as $comment) 
        {
            echo "Comment: ".$comment->Content;
        }
    }
    die();
    return view('welcome');
});
```

I can only get one element on each image, even though the image has more than 1 comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is in your comments relation:

```
 public function comments() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'CommentId');
    }
```

it should be:

```
 public function comments() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'ImageId');
    }
```

the second parameter in hasMany relation should be the foreign key that relate the two table in data base.

more details in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: You're absolutely rigth, that was it. Thanks so much